# Complex column and row reverse using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a sample dataframe, df, where I would like to maintain all columns in my original dataset and create a new pivoted column based on existing dataset. (grouped by id)
Original dataframe has about 80 columns

**Data**

```
 s1    s2    id q122c q122a q122c2 q122a2 q222c q222a q222c2 q222a2 q322c q322a q322c2 q322a2
 50    1000  aa 40    10    900   100      50    0     1000   0     60    -10   1100  -100
 100   2000  bb 50    50    1500  500      75    25    1900   100    100    0    2000  0
```

**Desired**

```
s1      s2      id  date    consumed1   avail1      consumed2   avail2  
50      1000    aa  q122    40          10          900         100             
50      1000    aa  q222    50          0           1000        0   
50      1000    aa  q322    60         -10          1100        -100
100     2000    bb  q122    50          50          1500        500             
100     2000    bb  q222    75          25          1900        100 
100     2000    bb  q322    100         0           2000        0
```

**Doing**

```
pd.wide_to_long(df.set_index(['stat1','stat2','id']).stack().groupby(level=[0,1,2,3]).agg(list).apply(pd.Series).unstack().stack(level=0).reset_index(),
                stubnames = ['q122','q222'], i = ['stat1','stat2','id','level_3'],j = 'date',suffix='\\w+').stack().unstack(level=[-3,-2])
```

A SO member has provided a script that will take the data from wide to long, however, the output I am getting is not capturing all the columns needed.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Why do u have duplicate columns in ur output?

Comment: let me update this @sammywemmy

Comment: cool, one more check, your input dataframe has duplicate columns as well. is that intentional? if that is the case, kindly provide a way to reproduce it; as it is, using `pd.read_clipboard` creates unique columns

Comment: I have updated @sammywemmy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to go about this:

One option is to convert the columns to a MultiIndex, then reshape with stack:

```py
index = ['s1', 's2', 'id']
temp = df.set_index(index)
temp.columns = temp.columns.str.split(r"([a|c]\d?)", expand = True).droplevel(-1)
temp.columns.names = ['date', None]
(temp.stack(level='date')
     .rename(columns={'c':'consumed1', 
                      'a':'avail1', 
                      'c2':'consumed2', 
                      'a2':'avail2'})
     .reset_index()
)

    s1    s2  id  date  avail1  avail2  consumed1  consumed2
0   50  1000  aa  q122      10     100         40        900
1   50  1000  aa  q222       0       0         50       1000
2   50  1000  aa  q322     -10    -100         60       1100
3  100  2000  bb  q122      50     500         50       1500
4  100  2000  bb  q222      25     100         75       1900
5  100  2000  bb  q322       0       0        100       2000
```

with `pd.wide_to_long`:

```py
index = ['s1', 's2', 'id']
temp = df.set_index(index)
temp.columns = temp.columns.str.split(r"([a|c]\d?)").str[::-1].str[1:].str.join('_')

(pd.wide_to_long(temp.reset_index(), 
                 stubnames = ['c', 'a', 'c2', 'a2'], 
                 i = index, 
                 j = 'date', 
                 sep='_', 
                 suffix='.+')
  .rename(columns={'c':'consumed1', 
                   'a':'avail1', 
                   'c2':'consumed2', 
                   'a2':'avail2'})
  .reset_index()
)

    s1    s2  id  date  consumed1  avail1  consumed2  avail2
0   50  1000  aa  q122         40      10        900     100
1   50  1000  aa  q222         50       0       1000       0
2   50  1000  aa  q322         60     -10       1100    -100
3  100  2000  bb  q122         50      50       1500     500
4  100  2000  bb  q222         75      25       1900     100
5  100  2000  bb  q322        100       0       2000       0
```

Another option is with  `pivot_longer` from `pyjanitor`, that offers a *simpler* way for such complex reshaping :

```py
#pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor
(df.pivot_longer(slice('s1', 'id'), 
                 names_to = ('date', '.value'), 
                 names_pattern = r"([a-z]\d+)(.+)", 
                 sort_by_appearance=True)
  .rename(columns={'c':'consumed1', 
                   'a':'avail1', 
                   'c2':'consumed2', 
                   'a2':'avail2'})
)
    s1    s2  id  date  consumed1  avail1  consumed2  avail2
0   50  1000  aa  q122         40      10        900     100
1   50  1000  aa  q222         50       0       1000       0
2   50  1000  aa  q322         60     -10       1100    -100
3  100  2000  bb  q122         50      50       1500     500
4  100  2000  bb  q222         75      25       1900     100
5  100  2000  bb  q322        100       0       2000       0
```

The `names_pattern` indicates how the columns will be reshaped. there are two values in `names_to`: ('date', '.value'). There are also two regex groups in `names_pattern`. The first regex group will be paired with `date` to form a new column, while the second regex group will be paired with `.value` to form new headers.

Comment: Ok let me try. My full dataset has a few more columns, so I’m thinking I could just adjust the renaming of the columns(with the last option). @sammywemmy I will also lookup pyjanitor thank u

Comment: Also is the ‘names_pattern’ used to isolate the date such as ‘q122’ etc? @sammywemmy

Comment: yes, so the first values go to date, the other stays as column headers

Comment: Ah brilliant- will check on this thank you

Comment: I updated the other options as well; Pandas allows multiple ways to do the same thing; the catch is in finding efficient paths that are simple (simple is always better)

Comment: This is a great solution, and easy to understand the layout. I will try w my dataset @sammywemmy thank you